# Use pylab to plot image returned from Scipy

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working to migrate from MatLab to python in Sage.
So I use these commands and I faced this error in Sage:

```
from scipy import misc

l = misc.lena();

import pylab as pl

pl.imshow(l)
```

The Error or message (i don't know) is:

```
matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0xb80198c
```

And it doesn't show any image

Comment: pl.show() or pl.draw(), try those. I don't think this is an error message, it's just telling you the object has been created

Answer (score 8):

It's not an error, just print the object that method returned.

There are two ways to show the figure:

1. Add **pl.show()** after calling **pl.imshow(l)**
2. Use **ipython --pylab** to open your python shell,

Answer (score 2):

That is an object being returned from pylab after using the "imshow" command. That is the location of the Axes image object.

documentation:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Looks like it says it displays the object to the current axes. If you havent already created a plot I imagine you wont see anything

Simple google search suggests this might be what you are looking for

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.lena.html

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work in Sage. I tried it on Spyder and it worked, I think it's some issues with Sage.

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy import misc
l = misc.lena();
import pylab as pl
pl.imshow(l)

####use this
pl.show()
```